# itext-2.1.7 throws FATAL error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Color

Tags: android, itext

I am using old version of itext (as new versions have some license issues) to generate PDF file, it was working smoothly with newer version of itext and droidtext as well, but i am getting run time error in this old version itext-2.1.7.
The error log is as follow:

```
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Color
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfChunk.color(Unknown Source)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.writeLineToContent(Unknown Source)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.flushLines(Unknown Source)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.newPage(Unknown Source)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(Unknown Source)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at com.lowagie.text.Document.close(Unknown Source)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at com.darshanmukadam.expensereports.PdfCreator.create_pdf(PdfCreator.java:195)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at com.darshanmukadam.expensereports.PdfCreator.access$0(PdfCreator.java:125)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at com.darshanmukadam.expensereports.PdfCreator$2.onItemClick(PdfCreator.java:108)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1490)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3275)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4518)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
09-25 17:33:49.035: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have search on google but i cant find any solutions, any idea whats going on ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library java.awt.* is not part of Android. Android uses different technology to create elements.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not have `java.awt.Color`. Your version of iText is incompatible with Android, at least for whatever content you poured into the `Document`.

Comment: Ok, so itext-2.1.7 uses java.awt.* which are incompatible with android, so is there any solution for this? is there any modified version of itext-2.1.7 which is compatible with android?

Comment: @Darshan: "is there any modified version of itext-2.1.7 which is compatible with android?" -- I have not looked for one, sorry.

Comment: You need to use [iTextG](http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg) which is the port of iText 5+. You shouldn't use iText 2.1.7 in production as there are many issues with that version, technical as well as legal issues. There are more licensing issues with iText 2.1.7 than there are with the AGPL version of iText. Of course: using iText 5 means that you obey the AGPL open source license.